# cmd command to replace all "-" with "_"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

On a Windows machine, I've got a bunch of files in numerous folders with the a dash in the filename.

By any chance is there a way to remove all the dashes in the filenames in the various folders and replace it with an underscore?

Comment: This seems close, but does not seem to address the folder structure.  That structure is something like: top_dir/lower_dir/2nd_lower_dir, top_dir/lower_dir/3rd_lower_dir, etc. I would like to address all files in those folders. My mistake on poorly wording this initial question.

Comment: And, "words 08-09-2013 words.pptx" became "words 08-09-2013 words.pptx_", so that is not exactly the hoped for result.  Thanks again for any thoughts.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to change dashes to underscores in both the folder names and the file names, or just the file names?

Comment: yep - filenames and foldernames...actually, this extends to other places as well...

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnabledelayedExpansion
for /r "c:\path\to\main folder\" %%a in (*) do (
set "newname=%%~na"
set "newname=!newname:-=_!"
ren "%%~a" "!newname!%%~xa"
)
```

And that should do what you want.

Comment: +1 Made some small changes.  Rename can't use a path in the target name.